# How to catch deserialize error in firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

How do I catch and make my app resilient for de-serialization errors in firestore?

This is my piece of code:

```
db.collection("ABC").whereEqualTo("some_enabled",true)
                .orderBy("index_abc", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(100)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {

                            return;
                        }
                        List<User> someList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : snapshots) {                     
                                someList.add(doc.toObject(User.class)); // deserialization error here
                        }

                        if(Fragment.this.getActivity() != null)
                        {
                            someAdapter = new UserGridAdapter(someList,mCurrentUser, Fragment.this.getActivity());
                            someRecyclerView.setAdapter(someAdapter);
                            someAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here's the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:563)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertInteger(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:411)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:320)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:226)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:189)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:54)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:770)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:741)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:542)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:253)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:100)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:210)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:188)
>   at
>   xyz.app.zingo.zingoapp.HomeScreen.Fragments.DiscoverFragment$1.onEvent
>   (DiscoverFragment.java:103)   at
>   xyz.app.zingo.zingoapp.HomeScreen.Fragments.DiscoverFragment$1.onEvent
>   (DiscoverFragment.java:100)

Comment: You have to creat an index at firebase to sort data

Comment: Hey @HoàngVũAnh, index is working fine. I'm talking about a deserialization error which occurs due to class type mismatch between the data in firestore and the POJO in the app.

Comment: Please add the content of your `User` class and the database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Well by judging where the error was thrown it looks like the CustomClassMapper.java throws a generic RuntimeException. So if you want to catch the error being thrown here, you would need to try catch a RuntimeException. See the [CustomClassMapper.java](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java).

However, I have to say this is not advisable since you will potentially mask other RuntimeExceptions that are not related to the deserialization.